# How to sort the elements of a recycler view in order of time that has implemented Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to order the elements of my recycler view that these photos are uploaded but they go in order from the oldest and to the last of the list are the most recent ones I found out but I do not know how to solve it

My recycler class this a fragment:

```
 public class PostFragment extends Fragment {

private View mRootView;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder> mPostAdapter;
private RecyclerView mPostRecyclerView;

public PostFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fabM);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PostCreateDialog dialog = new PostCreateDialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });
    init();
    return mRootView;
}

private void init() {
    mPostRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_post);
    mPostRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    setupAdapter();
    mPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);

}

private void setupAdapter() {
    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.row_post,
            PostHolder.class,
            FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setNumComments(String.valueOf(model.getNumComments()));
            viewHolder.setNumLikes(String.valueOf(model.getNumLikes()));
            viewHolder.setTime(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeCreated()));
            viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText(model.getUsername());
            if(viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView == null){
                viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText("Anonymous");
            }
            viewHolder.setPostText(model.getPostText());



                final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                        .getReference(model.getPostImageUrl());

            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageReference).crossFade().fitCenter().into(viewHolder.postDisplayImageView);






            viewHolder.postLikeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onLikeClick(model.getPostId());
                }
            });

            viewHolder.postCommentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CommentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_POST, model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });





        }
    };
}




private void onLikeClick(final String postId) {
    FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        //user liked
                        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
                                .child(postId)
                                .child("numLikes")
                                .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                                        mutableData.setValue(num - 1);
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
                                                .setValue(null);
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
                                .child(postId)
                                .child("numLikes")
                                .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                                        mutableData.setValue(num + 1);
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
                                                .setValue(true);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}

public static class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView postOwnerUsernameTextView;
    TextView postTimeCreatedTextView;

    ImageView postDisplayImageView;
    TextView postTextTextView;

    LinearLayout postLikeLayout;
    TextView postNumLikesTextView;

    LinearLayout postCommentLayout;
    TextView postNumCommentsTextView;



    public PostHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        postOwnerUsernameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_post_username);
        postTimeCreatedTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        postDisplayImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_post_display);
        postLikeLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_layout);
        postCommentLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
        postNumLikesTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes);
        postNumCommentsTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments);
        postTextTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_post_text);


    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText(username);
    }

    public void setTime(CharSequence time) {
        postTimeCreatedTextView.setText(time);
    }

    public void setNumLikes(String numLikes) {
        postNumLikesTextView.setText(numLikes);
    }

    public void setNumComments(String numComments) {
        postNumCommentsTextView.setText(numComments);
    }

    public void setPostText(String text) {
        postTextTextView.setText(text);
    }


}

}
```

and the post dialog Here is where you select the photos to upload:

```
    public class PostCreateDialog extends DialogFragment implements          View.OnClickListener {
private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 1;
private View mRootView;
private Post mPost;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
private ImageView mPostDisplay;
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    mPost = new Post();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    mRootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_create_dialog, null);
    mPostDisplay = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_display);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    builder.setView(mRootView);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview:
            sendPost();
            break;
        case R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview:
            selectImage();
            break;
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
}

private void sendPost() {
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Sending post...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    final String postUid = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
                    TextView postDialogTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_edittext);
                    String text = postDialogTextView.getText().toString();
                    RegisterActivity r = new RegisterActivity();

                    mPost.setNumComments(0);
                    mPost.setNumLikes(0);
                    mPost.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    mPost.setPostId(postUid);
                    mPost.setPostText(text);




                    if (mSelectedImageUri != null) {
                        FirebaseUtils.getImagesSRef()
                                .child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment())
                                .putFile(mSelectedImageUri)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(),
                                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                String url = Constants.POST_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment();
                                                //String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                                mPost.setPostImageUrl(url);
                                                addToMyPostList(postUid);
                                            }


                                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No puedes postear sin imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

private void addToMyPostList(final String postUid) {
    FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postUid)
            .setValue(mPost);
    FirebaseUtils.getMyPostRef().child(postUid).setValue(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

    FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.POSTS_KEY, postUid);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
            mPostDisplay.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the utlis:

```
   public static DatabaseReference getUserRef(String email) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.USERS_KEYS)
            .child(email);
}
public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}






// POST REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_KEY);
}
public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild(Constants.TIME_CREATED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.MY_POSTS)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}





// POST LIKED REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_LIKED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef(String postId) {
    return getPostLikedRef().child(getCurrentUser().getEmail()
            .replace(".", ","))
            .child(postId);
}








// USER ID
public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}







// POST IMAGE REFERENCE
public static StorageReference getImagesSRef() {
    return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(Constants.POST_IMAGES);
}








// COMMENT REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getCommentRef(String postId) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY)
            .child(postId);
}







// RECORD

public static DatabaseReference getMyRecordRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_RECORD)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}



public static void addToMyRecord(String node,final String id) {
    FirebaseUtils.getMyRecordRef().child(node).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            ArrayList<String> myPostCollection;
            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                myPostCollection = new ArrayList<>(1);
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            } else {
                myPostCollection = (ArrayList<String>) mutableData.getValue();
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: @Dskata use local or remote firebase database? or use only push remote messages?

Comment: I solved this with a RecyclerView property

Comment: plz publicate solve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void setupAdapter() {
    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(
        Post.class,
        R.layout.row_post,
        PostHolder.class,
       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.POSTS_KEY).orderByChild("TimeCreated")
    ) 
}
```